If I set AccessToken and RefreshToken both (JWT) as cookies by server, They both automatically will be sent to server in each request from client
In every login request I set AccessToken and RefreshToken both as Cookies in ASP.NET Core 8 WebApi Controller:
    [HttpHead("Auth/Login")]
    public async Task<IResult> Login([FromHeader] long phoneNumber)
    {
        AuthTokenDTO result = await _dBContext.User.Login(phoneNumber);
        if (result is null)
            return Results.BadRequest();

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
            "AccessToken",
            result.Token,
            new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(
                    int.Parse(_configuration["JWT:TknValidityInMunutes"])
                ),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                HttpOnly = true,
                Path = "/",
                Domain = ".localhost",
            }
        );

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
            "RefreshToken",
            result.RefreshToken,
            new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(
                    int.Parse(_configuration["JWT:RefTknValidityInHours"])
                ),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                HttpOnly = true,
                Path = "/",
                Domain = ".localhost",
            }
        );

        return Results.Ok();
    }

My Program.cs file:
 builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy
                .WithOrigins(["http://localhost:5173", "http://localhost:5247"])
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        }
    );
});
ConfigurationManager config = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(o => { });
builder
    .Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = config["JWT:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = config["JWT:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["JWT:Key"])),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0),
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"];
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", p => p.RequireClaim("IsAdmin", "True"))
);

Front is SvelteKit with FetchAPI:
promiseFunc: fetch('http://localhost:5247/Api/User/Auth/Login', {
        method: 'HEAD',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: { phoneNumber }
    }),

I need AccessToken cookie to be sent to the server in each request by client automatically, It works and that's ok, But the RefreshToken will being sent too in each request and as I know RefreshToken must not be sent in each request for security reasons, how can I handle this? do I have to not set RefreshToken in cookie and set it to localStorage and send it everytime i need by hand?

I would keep both tokens in cookies to reduce token threats in the browser. Just give the refresh cookie a path like /refresh where that is a path that you use to rewrite cookies with new tokens.
I tend to use cookie settings like these:
new CookieOptions
{
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    HttpOnly = true,
    Path = "/refresh",
}

Where:

SameSite=strict prevents other sites from sending the cookie
Removal of Domain means the cookie can't be sent my other origins
Removal of Expires makes it a session cookie that is removed when the user closes all browser windows


As you mentioned, For example if I go to '/refresh', the cookie (RefreshToken) will be activated, But For using RefreshToken, we shouldn't change the route, It must be used silently in background to Generate AccessToken again, how can I fixed it? activating a cookie without changing a route especially for RefreshToken

Usually your frontend would call a Refresh endpoint that your backend provides. The frontend would call it when an access token expires and it receives a 401 from the backend, or when the access token is close to expiry. This gives your frontend best control. The Refresh backend method would be similar to your existing Login method - it would read cookies, do the refresh, then rewrite cookies.
